# Access real-time video frames

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently, I am trying to develop an AR application. I am able to record video using this script on HoloLens. Now, I want to access real-time camera feeds for image processing. How should I modify this script to get real-time video frames? OR How can I get real-time frames in Texture2D? I will be passing those frames to my DLL for some image processing.

```
public class VideoCaptureExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    static readonly float MaxRecordingTime = 5.0f;

    VideoCapture m_VideoCapture = null;
    float m_stopRecordingTimer = float.MaxValue;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        StartVideoCaptureTest();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (m_VideoCapture == null || !m_VideoCapture.IsRecording)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (Time.time > m_stopRecordingTimer)
        {
            m_VideoCapture.StopRecordingAsync(OnStoppedRecordingVideo);
        }
    }

    void StartVideoCaptureTest()
    {

        Resolution cameraResolution = VideoCapture.SupportedResolutions.OrderByDescending((res) => res.width * res.height).First();
        Debug.Log(cameraResolution);

        float cameraFramerate = VideoCapture.GetSupportedFrameRatesForResolution(cameraResolution).OrderByDescending((fps) => fps).First();
        Debug.Log(cameraFramerate);

        VideoCapture.CreateAsync(false, delegate (VideoCapture videoCapture)
        {
            if (videoCapture != null)
            {
                m_VideoCapture = videoCapture;
                Debug.Log("Created VideoCapture Instance!");

                CameraParameters cameraParameters = new CameraParameters();
                cameraParameters.hologramOpacity = 0.0f;
                cameraParameters.frameRate = cameraFramerate;
                cameraParameters.cameraResolutionWidth = cameraResolution.width;
                cameraParameters.cameraResolutionHeight = cameraResolution.height;
                cameraParameters.pixelFormat = CapturePixelFormat.BGRA32;

                m_VideoCapture.StartVideoModeAsync(cameraParameters,
                                                   VideoCapture.AudioState.ApplicationAndMicAudio,
                                                   OnStartedVideoCaptureMode);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("Failed to create VideoCapture Instance!");
            }
        });
    }

    void OnStartedVideoCaptureMode(VideoCapture.VideoCaptureResult result)
    {
        Debug.Log("Started Video Capture Mode!");
        string timeStamp = Time.time.ToString().Replace(".", "").Replace(":", "");
        string filename = string.Format("TestVideo_{0}.mp4", timeStamp);
        string filepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, filename);
        filepath = filepath.Replace("/", @"\");
        m_VideoCapture.StartRecordingAsync(filepath, OnStartedRecordingVideo);
    }

    void OnStoppedVideoCaptureMode(VideoCapture.VideoCaptureResult result)
    {
        Debug.Log("Stopped Video Capture Mode!");
    }

    void OnStartedRecordingVideo(VideoCapture.VideoCaptureResult result)
    {
        Debug.Log("Started Recording Video!");
        m_stopRecordingTimer = Time.time + MaxRecordingTime;
    }

    void OnStoppedRecordingVideo(VideoCapture.VideoCaptureResult result)
    {
        Debug.Log("Stopped Recording Video!");
        m_VideoCapture.StopVideoModeAsync(OnStoppedVideoCaptureMode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Unity's VideoPlayer component. See docs [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-VideoPlayer.html):

```
void Start()
    {
        // Will attach a VideoPlayer to the main camera.
        GameObject camera = GameObject.Find("Main Camera");

        // VideoPlayer automatically targets the camera backplane when it is added
        // to a camera object, no need to change videoPlayer.targetCamera.
        var videoPlayer = camera.AddComponent<UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer>();

        // Play on awake defaults to true. Set it to false to avoid the url set
        // below to auto-start playback since we're in Start().
        videoPlayer.playOnAwake = false;

        // By default, VideoPlayers added to a camera will use the far plane.
        // Let's target the near plane instead.
        videoPlayer.renderMode = UnityEngine.Video.VideoRenderMode.CameraNearPlane;

        // This will cause our Scene to be visible through the video being played.
        videoPlayer.targetCameraAlpha = 0.5F;

        // Set the video to play. URL supports local absolute or relative paths.
        // Here, using absolute.
        videoPlayer.url = filepath;

        // Skip the first 100 frames.
        videoPlayer.frame = 100;

        // Restart from beginning when done.
        videoPlayer.isLooping = true;

        // Each time we reach the end, we slow down the playback by a factor of 10.
        videoPlayer.loopPointReached += EndReached;

        // Start playback. This means the VideoPlayer may have to prepare (reserve
        // resources, pre-load a few frames, etc.). To better control the delays
        // associated with this preparation one can use videoPlayer.Prepare() along with
        // its prepareCompleted event.
        videoPlayer.Play();
    }

    void EndReached(UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer vp)
    {
        vp.playbackSpeed = vp.playbackSpeed / 10.0F;
    }
```